# Laravel passport - refresh token problem with bad connection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

There is API on Laravel, which uses Laravel Passport for authentication. All worked well with the default settings. Then we decided to change the lifetime of the access token to 1 day and 1 month accordingly. It caused a problem with the refresh token. 
Example: Access token is expired and the app sends the refresh token request to API. Then the app loses internet connection and can't get a new token. (Server sends new tokens but the app is unavailable). After the internet connection returned, the app sends a new refresh request but get 401. So apps need to get new code from API to authenticate the user. I don't think it's a good idea to force the user to login every day.
Any suggestions? Maybe there is some way like "handshake" to solve that problem? I mean refresh token only after confirmation the app got new tokens.

Comment: What does it related to changing passport settings?! If you are requesting refresh token and you loss connection then you have to try again by old token and refresh token. It does not related to your change. If you are dropping old token when providing new token i think you can add new endpoint to validate new token and then drop old one.

Comment: `If you are requesting refresh token and you loss connection then you have to try again by old token and refresh token.` You do not understand my case. The user is loosing connecting during refresh token request, the server has changed access and refresh token, but the user hasn't got it. So user has old creds, but there are new on server.  Passport setting are not important in question, the major thing is refresh token only after confirmation the app got new tokens

Comment: Yes i understood, and i said you have to add validate token endpoint for new token, after validate revoke old token. Of course there will be other cases which you have to handle it, for example you have to try refresh token before expiration time.

Answer (score 4):

If I correctly understand your question, you're saying that you initially have an `Access Token1, Refresh Token1` pair, and when the `Access Token1`  expired you try to request a new `Access Token` using the `Refresh Token1`.

Now, for some reason, you fail to receive this new  `Access Token2, Refresh Token2` pair, so what does the user do?. Well, you see this from the Consumer's point of view. If you see the same scenario from the Oauth2 Server's point of view.

The Server does not know if you failed to receive the token or you received it and failed to save. The server's job was to generate a new access token based on your valid refresh token. And as soon as it creates a new access token, it invalidates the old refresh token. This is the standard Oauth2 implementation.

You may try to make it so that the Old refresh token is not immediately revoked on new access token generation. But this introduces a possibility of replay attacks.

Hence, The standard practice is to have the User log-in again.

Comment: thx, I understand the logic of Oauth2, I just wanna discover if there is a standard way to get around this behavior in Laravel

Comment: @V-K afaik there is no standard way to not have a refresh token expire in Passport